# How to add grouping variable to data set that will classify both an observation and its N neighbors based on some condition

Tags: r

I am having some trouble coming up with a solution that properly handles classifying a variable number of neighbors for any given observation in a data frame based on some condition. I would like to be able to add a simple, binary indicator variable to a data frame that will equal 1 if the condition is satisfied, and 0 if it is not.

Where I am getting stuck is I am unsure how to iteratively check the condition against neighboring observations only, in either direction (i.e., to check if out of 4 neighboring observations in a given column in my data frame, that at least 3 out of 4 of them contain the same value). I have tried first creating another indicator variable indicating if the condition is satisfied or not (1 or 0 = yes or no). Then, I tried setting up a series of `ifelse()` statements within a loop to try to assign the proper categorization of the observation where the initial condition is satisfied, +/- 2 observations in either direction. However, when I inspect the dataframe after running the loop, only the observation itself (not its neighbors) where the condition is satisfied is receiving the value, rather than all neighboring observations also receiving the value. Here is my code:

```
#sample data
sample_dat <- data.frame(initial_ind = c(0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0))

sample_dat$violate <- NULL
for(i in 1:nrow(dat_date_ord)){
  sample_dat$violate[i] <- ifelse(sample_dat$initial_ind[i]==1 &
                                         ((sample_dat$initial_ind[i-2]==1 |
                                             sample_dat$initial_ind[i-1]==1) &
                                            (sample_dat$initial_ind[i+2]==1 |
                                               sample_dat$initial_ind[i+1]==1)),
                                       "trending",
                                       "non-trending"
  )
}
```

This loop correctly identifies one of the four points that needs to be labelled "trending", but it does not also assign "trending" to the correct neighbors. In other words, I expect the output to be "trending for observations 7-10, since 3/4 observations in that group of 4 all have a value of 1 in the initial indicator column. I feel like there might be an easier way to accomplish this - but what I need to ensure is that my code is robust enough to identify and assign observations to a group regardless of if I want 3/4 to indicate a group, 5/6, 2/5, etc.

Thank you for any and all advice.

Comment: Accepting @Luis' edited answer - achieves desired outcome at the group-level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `rollapply` function from the `zoo` package to apply a function to set intervals in your data. The question then becomes about creating a function that satisfies your needs. I'm not sure if I've understood correctly, but it seems you want a function that checks if the condition is true for at least 3/5 of the observation plus its four closest neighbors. In this case just adding the 1s up and checking if they're above 2 works.

```
library(zoo)

sample_dat <- data.frame(initial_ind = c(0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0))

trend_test = function(x){
  ifelse(sum(x) > 2, "trending", "non-trending")
}

sample_dat$violate_new = rollapply(sample_dat$initial_ind, FUN = trend_test, width = 5, fill = NA)
```

Edit: If you want a function that checks if the observation and the next 3 observations have at least 3 1s, you can do something very similar, just by changing the `align` argument on rollapply:

```
trend_test_2 = function(x){
  ifelse(sum(x) > 2, "trending", "non-trending")
}

sample_dat$violate_new = rollapply(sample_dat$initial_ind, FUN = trend_test_2, width = 4, 
  fill = NA, align = "left")
```

Comment: Hi Luis thank you for your answer. I tried your solution and it is still not quite achieving what I want. My apologies for the confusion - what I want is the value in the new column to be set to "trending" if 3/4 consecutive observations have a value of 1 in the "initial_ind" column. So, in my case with the `sample_dat` data frame, only rows 7-10 should have "trending", and all other rows should be "non-trending". Does that help to clarify things?

Comment: I'm confused, because 4 is an even number. An observation plus its closest neighbors is 3 observations. An observation plus its closest and second closest  neighbors is 5 observations.

Comment: Apologies - perhaps I can explain it in a different way. Rather than think about it in terms of neighbors +/- observations, would it make more sense to treat every 4 observations as a group first? Meaning, observations 1-4 comprise group 1, observations 2-5 comprise group 2, etc. Then, check in each group if 3/4 observations have a 1 for "initial_ind", and if yes, assign "trending"? If thinking about it in terms of neighbors, the number of neighbors above/below each observation will fluctuate based on the index of the observation that is being checked.

Comment: I don't think your suggestion does what you think it does. Take for example observation 8. It would be part of group 8, which is 8-11. There are two 1s in that, so it would be "not trending", not "trending". Check my edit.

Comment: Correct about observation 8 - it is in group #8, and there are only 2 initial_ind =1 in that group, so the value for group #8 as a whole should be "not trending". However, observation 8 is also in group #7, and for that group there are 3/4 1's, so group #7 as a whole should be assigned "trending". So I suppose the question becomes - would I need to output a much larger data set, repeating the row number for the number of times it appears in a distinct group?

Comment: Follow-up: I think that your edit is perhaps assigning the correct output of "trending"/"non-trending" to the group number, but treating group number as row number? For example, your revised code produces "trending" for row 7 - which in reference to my last comment, would be the correct assignment for that group number.

Comment: Observation 8 is "trending" in group 7, but is "not-trending" in groups 5, 6 and 8. Are you sure you want to classify 8 as "trending"? Is being "trending" in at least one group sufficient for you to call it "trending" overall?

Comment: You are right - that is something I did not consider well-enough before, and I will need to decide how to output my final data set.

I just checked your solution with a new data set - it seems to be doing exactly what I mentioned  in my last comment, which ultimately gets me the output at the group-level that I desire. Thank you very much, and I am accepting your answer now :)